# Photoshop script rename visible layer after file

Tags: photoshop, layer

could you help me with a Photoshop script that renames the visible layers after the file name ?

I have an insane number of PS files for which I have to do it.

Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this for example:

```
function selectByID(id)
{
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putIdentifier(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), id);
    desc.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref);
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID('slct'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
};

function traverseAllLayers(n)
{
    try
    {
        activeDocument.backgroundLayer;
        var layers = 0
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        var layers = 1;
    };
    while (true)
    {
        ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), layers);
        try
        {
            var desc = executeActionGet(ref);
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (desc.getBoolean(charIDToTypeID("Vsbl")) && desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("layerKind")) != 13) {
            var myId = desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID( 'layerID' ));
            selectByID(myId);
            activeDocument.activeLayer.name = activeDocument.name
        }
        layers++;
    }

};

app.activeDocument.suspendHistory("temp", "traverseAllLayers()");
```

Comment: Hi! Yes but this one seems to rename just the first layer/group of layers. The visible layer remains with the initial name. Thanks.

Comment: yeah it didn't work correctly with groups, I updated my answer

Comment: Do you know how it could work in batch? If I open multiple files, it renames just the last file opened. Thanks!

Comment: Just loop through documents. Also I'd appreciate if you'd accept this answer if it worked.

Comment: It seems it works in batch just with some PS versions. I tried 19 (CC 2018) and it worked.